# Grunt serve: Bad request

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I'v recently switched from http://brunch.io to Yeoman/Grunt, so I'm a newbie. I'm developing an Angular App, everything worked fine, but all of a sudden I'm now getting this error for grunt serve:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Error: Bad Request
at SendStream.error (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:239:16)
at SendStream.pipe (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:411:32)
at Object.serveStatic [as handle] (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:111:12)
at next (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Object.livereload [as handle] (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect-livereload/index.js:92:14)
at next (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:174:15)
at Function.app.handle (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:182:3)
at Server.app (/Users/ched/Documents/Office/test2/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:67:37)
at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
```

Apart from this message in the terminal everything seems to work though, so I can see my app running in the browser. I haven't installed or deinstall new components, so I don't have any clue where this message comes from and how to fix this.

**Update:** It works randomly now every fifth or sixth time I'm saving a file. Is there any way of reinstalling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that the reason for this are files that are pictures that can't be found.